# HTML and Python : How to make variables in a html code written in a python script

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import re

htmlDoc="""
<html>
<body>

<table class="details" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" style="width:95%">
  <tr>
    <td>Roll No.</td>
    <td><b>Subject 1</b></td>       
    <td>Subject 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>01</td>
    <td>Absent</td>     
    <td>Present</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>02</td>
    <td>Absent</td>     
    <td>Absent</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlDoc,"lxml")

#table = soup.find("table",attrs={class:"details"})



html = soup.prettify("utf-8")
with open("/home/alan/html_/output.html", "wb") as file:
    file.write(html)
```

I've used BeautifulSoup to write the HTML code. In the code, the variable I'vve to make is Present, Absent. Upon change of some parameter, I've to change the values, change present to absent and vice versa. 
I've to make pesent/absent a variable 'a'.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It isn't clear exactly what problem you are encountering. Consider including a small fragment of what inputs you have (including program variables, not just the HTML) and exactly what output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean composing your own html from some form on python data using BeautifulSoup? If so, the example below may be useful to you:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
import os

subjects = ['subject1', 'subject2']
vals = [['absent','present'],['absent','absent']] #rows

titles = ['Roll No.'] + subjects

html = """<html>
              <body>
                  <table class="details" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" style="width:95%">
                  </table>
              </body>
          </html>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

#find table tag
table = soup.find('table')

#add header to table tag
tr = Tag(table, name = 'tr')
for title in titles:
    td = Tag(tr, name = 'td')
    td.insert(0, title)
    tr.append(td)
table.append(tr)

#add data to table one row at a time
for i in range(len(vals[0])):

    tr = Tag(table, name = 'tr')

    td = Tag(tr, name = 'td')
    td.string = str(i+1)
    tr.append(td)

    for val in vals[i]:
        td = Tag(tr, name = 'td')
        td.string = val
        tr.append(td)

    table.append(tr)

os.chdir(os.getcwd())
f = open('test.html','w')
f.write(soup.prettify())
f.close()
```

Comment: a big thankyou, this is what u've been searching. the code i require will need some modifications. I'll try to make those, if i have any doubts, i'll ask :)

Comment: i need a program so that, i could store about 10 students attendance in a html file, the attendance(whether present or absent) will be obtained from an array. so how will i do that?